create conda recipe for drug2cell tool
I am building a recipe for drug2cell tool from it's github repo, the package is built successfully but it fails the test. here is my meta.yaml file content
{% set name = "drug2cell" %}
{% set version = "main" %}
{% set sha256 = "a6353f989f92f05b36972d42795f7f071245d351bf05027dc7e3e4a074ea5bb8" %}
package:
  name: {{ name|lower }}
  version: {{ version }}
source:
  url: https://github.com/teichlab/drug2cell/archive/main.tar.gz
  sha256: {{ sha256 }}
build:
  noarch: python
  number: 0
  script: {{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . --no-deps --ignore-installed -vv

requirements:
  host:
    - python
    - pip
  run:
    - python
    - anndata
   - pandas
    - numpy
    - statsmodels
    - scipy  
    - blitzgsea
test:
  commands:
    - drug2cell --version

The error that I get is
drug2cell --version
/opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/drug2cell_1732816346257/test_tmp/run_test.sh: line 7: drug2cell: command not found
WARNING: Tests failed for drug2cell-main-py_0.tar.bz2 - moving package to /opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/broken

CondaBuildUserError: TESTS FAILED: drug2cell-main-py_0.tar.bz2



There is no mention on https://github.com/Teichlab/drug2cell that it is usable as a command line tool and I don't see any entry points defined in setup.py. So Id on't see how drug2cell --version could be expected to work. Maybe you want something more like python -c "import drug2cell" to test succesfull installation

Thanks a lot! I changed the test and now it works
